# Using Python to recover data

Tags: python, hard-drive, data-recovery

I've just been given a hard drive that I need to recover. It seems the hard drive spins up and works for about 2-3 seconds and then stops. using `copy f:\*.docx c:\folder` I was able to get a few files off but I was thinking I need a slightly more permanent solution and one that could try and save 100mb+ files.

What I was thinking was using python to build lists of all the files and then attempt to read files out, marking them off as it finished. I'm not experienced with python or other languages but I was thinking something like a byte stream might be usable to get big files off in chunks. Can anyone provide guidance on using python to pull files like this?

Comment: why not use existing solutions? you're doing this as a challenge?

Comment: `PhotoRec` is the best tool to recover lost files - http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Comment: @ReutSharabani Hi, yeah I was thinking it was a chance to do some basic looping, file management and bytearray stuff in python.. EDIT: Mind you I also hadn't found a suitable program to do what I'm describing..

Comment: @furas thanks, I might check it out. As I said though from my symptoms I believe something like python could also do it. I'm just not that clear on pulling incomplete files..

Comment: @furas I tried photorec. Interestingly it can read contsantly from the sectors but reckons itll take 300 hours (and it's increasing)... Any ideas of how to get the data (and preserve filnames etc) without waiting weeks?